# Perl replace strings in XML file if unequal

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file with values like the following:

```
<values val1="4124" val2="21341"></values>
<values val1="1234" val2="231"></values>
<values val1="814" val2="8943"></values>
```

I would like to make `val2` assume the value of `val1` in all cases where they're unequal.

So the above would become:

```
<values val1="4124" val2="4124"></values>
<values val1="1234" val2="1234"></values>
<values val1="814" val2="814"></values>
```

Here is what I have:

```
perl -pi -e 's,val2=\"[0-9]*\,val1=\"[0-9]*\,g;' *
```

I am mainly having trouble understanding how to substitute the value of val1 to val2.  My above code will do this:

```
<values val1="4124" val1="4124"></values>
```

Comment: This problem becomes pretty trivial if you use an XML parser.

Comment: @MattJacob I'm not too familiar with string replacements in perl let alone XML parsers in perl tbqh.  I want to try to get down the basic pattern matching constructs if possible.

Comment: Perhaps these [search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+libxml+or+twig) will be helpful for you.

Comment: [On parsing XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2566198)

Comment: Re " I'm not too familiar with string replacements in perl let alone XML parsers in perl tbqh.", If you don't know either, all the more reason to use the right approach!!

Comment: As a warning, the insults directed at other users must stop right now. I have removed all of the offending comments, so let's keep this polite and on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_file($ARGV[0]);
   for my $node ($doc->findnodes("//@values")) {
      $node->setAttribute("val2", $node->getAttribute("val1"));
   }
   print($doc->toString());
' infile.xml >outfile.xml
```

- `$parser->parse_file` parses the file.
- `$doc->findnodes` finds nodes in the document.
- `$node->getAttribute` gets a node's attribute
- `$node->setAttribute` sets a node's attribute

Comment: Hmm. Code-only, one-line non-portable solution. What's not to like?

Comment: @Borodin, What are you talking about? It is documented. The OP wants a one-liner. It is portable. At least we agree it is a solution. /// I added some extra documentation for people like you.

Comment: @ikegami It might be a stretch to say the OP _wanted_ a one-liner. But since he presented that as his attempt, I don't think there's anything wrong with answering in kind.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: what follows definitely constitutes a hacky one-liner. If you want to do this properly, follow the advice and other answer and use a proper XML parser.

While it would be cleaner to use an XML parser, if your input is literally as you have it, you might be able to get away with using regular expression matching groups.

From the documentation http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Extracting-matches

> The grouping metacharacters () also allow the extraction of the parts of a string that matched. For each grouping, the part that matched inside goes into the special variables $1 , $2 , etc.

It's worth reading the whole page. Then you can try:

```
perl -pi -e 's/<values val1="([0-9]+)" val2="[0-9]+"><\/values>/<values val1="$1" val2="$1"><\/values>/g;'
```

Comment: I'm always ambivalent when someone posts an answer like this. Because on one hand, it's technically correct. But on the other, it's a bodge, and as such not as useful to future readers as an example of how to do it right.

Comment: I get what you (and everyone else) are saying but it's undeniable that perl/sed/whatever are useful for quick hacks like this. I will add a note to my answer because it's a fair point about future people finding this question.

Comment: Agreed. And I would by lying if I said I had never done it. But at the same time, it does lead to brittle solutions - one day it might just not cope with semantically identical XML and just break for no apparent reason.  I have been burned by similar things that have made their way into production.